# Assign javascript array to c# List

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.Net App and I have a simple view model with a List property as:

```
public List<int> SelectedStations { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Then via javascript I populate an array as:

```
     var stations=[];

     stations.push({
                     StationId:grid.dataItem(this).StationId,
                  });
```

So If I debug this it return data as following:

[image]

So it works, now I have an Ajax call to send this view model to controller as:

```
var data = {
        ...
        SelectedStations: stations
    }

  $.ajax({
                            url:'/Test/Create/',
                            data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ model: data }),
                            method: 'POST',
                            success: function(){
                                   setTimeout(function() {
                                         location.reload();
                                   }, 1000);
                            },
                        });
```

But the controller is always receiving list as empty list, what am I doing wrong?

`console.log(data)` result before send to ajax:

[image]

Controller receive it as:

[image]

Comment: What are the parameters of the controller function?  Does it match what you are sending?

Comment: My controller is like: `public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MyViewModel model)`, I'm sure the model it is working because I have more properties in and I'm receiving the correct data, but that list is always empty @hijinxbassist

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show before doing the ajax call?

Comment: I add an image to my question of the console.log(data), also added how it is receiving on the controller @JonP

Comment: @Demian  Your controller expects a list of numbers (List<int>) , but in javascript it's not an array of int, like `[5, 6]`, it's an array of objects `[{StationId: 5}, {StationId: 6}]`. Either adapt the mapping on the controller or before the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller expects an array of int like `[4, 3]`, whereas the ajax calls sends a list of *objects* `[{StationId: 4}, {StationId: 3}]`.

Even if each object contains a single int, the types don't match.

As solution, you can for instance build an array of numbers instead:

```
stations.push(grid.dataItem(this).StationId);
```

Alternatively, you can amend the controller and define another C# model that has a StationId property.